# Call a function on completion of data fetching from server Swift

Tags: swift

I have a method in which my data fetching is performing and I have a HUD view which I want to hide as soon as the data fetching is completed. My Hud start when a view load. Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   HUD.show(.progress)
}

func fetchData() {
    // performs fetch data
    HUD.hide(afterDelay: 1.0)
}
```

When data fetch is completed I want to hide HUD view. I wrote this hide function at the end of the method but its stop even before the data fetching is completed.

Comment: The method which fetch data probably running in an asynchronous way. Place the code at the completion block of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `closure` in `swift` to achieve what you are trying to do.

**Example:**

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    HUD.show(.progress)
    fetchData {
        HUD.hide(afterDelay: 1.0)
    }
}

func fetchData(completionHandler:(()->())?)
{
    //TODO: fetch you data
    //After data is fetched call completionHandler
    completionHandler?()
}
```